# Responsive layout in which left column may move to the right

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox

Say we have this responsive design with 3 columns (all 3 are dynamic contents so we don't know their heights)

For desktop:

[image]

For tablet (left column moves to the right)

[image]

What's the best way we can achieve this? (I don't mind using flexbox or other modern css specs)

Comment: You can use bootstrap `cols-sm-push`  and `cols-sm-pull` methods to acheive tihs

Comment: are you using bootstrap css?

Comment: @MukeshPrajapat & Suresh: nope I don't use bootstrap. I don't think bootstrap's grid can solve this case, because the placement of block 3 depends on block 1's height in tablet layout

Comment: you can make it using flexbox, take a look in http://flexbox.io

Answer (score 1):

You can make the elements make `float: left` on desktop with with 1/3 width each, then on tablet/mobile give them 50% width and make 1 and 3 `float: right`.

HTML:

```
<div class="b1">
  1
</div>
<div class="b2">
  2
</div>
<div class="b3">
  3
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100%/3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  div {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .b1,
  .b3 {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

[**Working JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/orf78pv2/3/)

Answer (score 1):

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid #333;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
}
.div1{
  background : yellow;
  width: 25%;
}
.div2{
  background : red;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 400px;
}
.div3{
  background : purple;
  width: 25%;
}
@media (max-width: 768px){
  .div1, .div3{
clear: right;
float: right;
width: 30%;
  }
  .div2{
width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo reiciendis sapiente cumque optio incidunt, dolore impedit officiis ut tempore. Pariatur commodi perspiciatis ducimus laudantium atque sed eveniet explicabo animi ipsam!</div>
<div class="div2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo reiciendis sapiente cumque optio incidunt, dolore impedit officiis ut tempore. Pariatur commodi perspiciatis ducimus laudantium atque sed eveniet explicabo animi ipsam!</div>
<div class="div3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo reiciendis sapiente cumque optio incidunt, dolore impedit officiis ut tempore. Pariatur commodi perspiciatis ducimus laudantium atque sed eveniet explicabo animi ipsam!</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yuywh5gv/

Comment: oh I've tried this way before but had a mistake with the width so it didn't work, now it's fine :) Btw it seems the 2 `clear: right` is not really necessary isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it might help. You can edit CSS as your wish

HTML code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"> 1 </div>
  <div class="middle">2 </div>
  <div class="right"> 3 </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.wrapper div {float:left;margin-right:.5%;text-align:center;}
.wrapper div:last-child {margin-right:0;}
.left {background: yellow; width:33%}
.middle {background: green; width:33%}
.right {background: blue; width:33%}
```

Answer (score 0):

# Phone only screen and (max-width:320px) # Tablet only screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-width:768px) # Desktop only screen and (min-width:769px)

```
  <div class="b1 col" >1</div>
  <div class="b2 con">2</div>
  <div class="b3 col">3</div>
```

add style bellow ::

```
       div {
           border: 2px solid black;
           padding: 20px;
           float: left;
           box-sizing: border-box;
       }

       .con{
           width: 66.66%;
        }

       div.col {
                width: 16.5%;
       }

       .b1 {
            height: 50px;
            border-color: #ee8;
       }

       .b2 {
            height: 200px;
            border-color: #fcc;
       }

       .b3 {
            height: 80px;
            border-color: #caf;
        }

        @media screen and (min-width:321px) and (max-width:768px)  {
        div.col {
           width: 33.33%;
        }
        .b1,
        .b3 {
          float: right;
        }
  }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3h32jd91/)